# Android клиент с загрузкой изображений

Tags: java, android, клиент-сервер

Есть сервер и android-клиент, вопрос: как правильно загружать фотографии с сервера в RecyclerView (или в ListView). Пока использую Picasso с записью в кеш, но сомнительно, что это правильный и грамотный способ. Никаких свежих, хороших статей не нахожу. Может, использовать Picasso, но без кэша, а всегда загружать с сервера? Приложение по доставке еды, загружать нужно фото блюд. В приложениях типа DeliveryClub или ZakaZaka хеш чистый, но изображения загружаются моментально. Как это реализуется у них?

Comment: А вы почём знаете, что они кэш не используют?.. Из данных о приложении?.. Они же могут картинки закэшировать и в другую папку, хоть на карту памяти. И тогда кэш есть, а удалить его можно только через файловый менеджер.

Comment: Не сомневайтесь, это правильный и грамотный способ. Не хранить картинки в кэше имеет смысл только если они очень часто обновляются или очень редко показываются в приложении больше одного раза.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Да, из данных о приложении. Не догадался до этого, вот бы где узнать точно, как у них реализовано.

Comment: @Sam узнать можно если посмотреть их исходники или создателей спросить. Но в любом случае xlor всё верно сказал про картинки и кэш. Ну и проверьте есть ли на девайсе где-то папки этих приложений.